# How can I pass a page param in Django url template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-pagination

I'm creating a simple search application. I have a model with some data, and the index page is just a search bar that search results of that model. I'm creating the form using just HTML, not a proper Django Form.

index.html:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'core:search' %}?page=1&q={{ request.GET.q }}">
   <div class="form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="search" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
      <label for="floatingInput">Type your search</label>
   </div>
   <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

The results are paginated, so I need that the url requested by the form is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?page=1&q=query`, `query` being the search term typed in the input. But what I wrote in the `action` parameter in the form doesn't work as I expected: even though it's writen `action="{% url 'core:search' %}?page=1&q={{ request.GET.q }}`, the URL requested is just `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=query`. The `page` param simply doesn't show up.

I wrote `page=1` because, as is the search result, the first one requested is always the first page.

The view that process this request is the `search_view`. I'm putting it below just as more info, but I think the problem is my misunderstanding of `url` template tag in the `action` form parameter.

search_view:

```
def search_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    page_num = request.GET.get('page')

    paginator = Paginator(posts.annotate(
        search=SearchVector('post_title', 'post_subtitle'),
    ).filter(search=query).order_by('post_title'), 15)

    num_results = paginator.count
    num_pages = paginator.num_pages

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page_num)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'num_results': num_results,
        'num_pages': num_pages,
        'page_range': paginator.page_range,
    }

    return render(request, 'core/search.html', context)
```

How can I make the URL requested be like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?page=1&q=query` ?

Comment: No need to send the page _always_, Just write: `request.GET.get('page', '1')`. Although aren't you handling that in your try except? Why do you need the page in the GET parameters for the first page anyway?

Comment: Because I trying to create a paginator that have a previous and a next button, but it doesn't show all page numbers. For example, if I have 9 pages, I want that my paginator show only the active page (5, for example), two pages before that (3 and 4) and two after (6 and 7). For doing this I need to do some math with the page number. But as page is not passed in the first request, my code becomes not too DRY for my taste.

Comment: `page.number`? For you since the page object is named `posts` you can write `posts.number`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Page.number